# Allowing multiple arguments or a single array argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, ruby-1.9, argument-passing

Often, I want to give flexibility to the form of arguments, and expect either a single array argument or multiple arguments that are to be handled together as a single array. So the following two usages will result in the same thing.

```
foo([arg1, arg2, ...])
foo(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

What is the best way to implement such method?

Comment: How would the user pass a single parameter which is an array then?

Comment: @MladenJablanović I implicitly had in mind that no trivial argument(s) i.e., that corresponds to an array with length one, will be passed. But that might not be a neat idea as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
def foo(*bar)
  bar.flatten!
  p bar #or whatever
end
```

This will ensure that no matter what is entered, you get a single flat array out of it.

Comment: This has a slight problem when each element is itself an array.

Comment: What problem would that be? Do you want something other than a single array as output? Because you asked for a single array.

Comment: No I am saying that, when `bar` is originally `[[arg1], [arg2], [arg3], ...]`, it will be converted to `[arg1, arg2, arg3, ...]`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you wanted.

Comment: Evidently not. If you had specified what you wanted, I may have been able to help.

Comment: @sawa, I see you've unaccepted my answer. I assume this means you're "re-opening" this question. Please update the question with example output that shows what you want.